# Python installing Module Requests

Tags: python, module

Whenever I run this command in the Python interface, it's comes up as "Invalid syntax"

```
>>> pip install Requests
File "<stdin>", line 1
pip install Requests
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone give me suggestions?

Comment: do it without the quotes.

Comment: Still returns invalid, apparently the Install is invalid

Comment: Please share the whole command output with the complete error message. According to the documentation you should type `pip install requests`.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the `>>>` primary prompt is present, which means you are inside a Python interpreter and running it in the interactive mode. Therefore, what you were trying to do is to run `pip install requests` inside the Python interpreter, which is not how you use `pip` to install packages from PyPI.

What you should do is to exit the Python interpreter and then back in your terminal, type

```
pip install requests
```

Answer (score 2):

To install Requests,run this simple command in your terminal of choice:

```
 pip install requests
```

Comment: That's exactly what I have done, its returning with an syntax error

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you using?

It looks like you have started the Python interpreter before you typed install requests.
Try opening a terminal window and typing pip install requests. That's assuming you have pip however.